# displaying last index arrow issue

Tags: javascript

I am displaying a values from with arrow like this

> ABC--->DES--->FDD--->BGR--->

It's working fine but I don't want to display last arrow because it doesn't make any sense. How can I resolve this?

```js
let network = ['ABC', 'DES', 'FDD', 'BGR'];

for (i = 0; i < network.length; i++) {
  temp = "<span style = 'border:3px dotted #399bff;'>" + network[i] + "</span><bold style = 'color : #d77300;'> <i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i></bold>";
  network[i] = temp;
}

console.log(network.join());
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because your loop adds the arrow to the end of *every* item in the array.

To fix the issue you can use `map()` to wrap each item in a `span`, and then use `join()` separately to combine each element in to a single string with the arrow image between them.

In addition, don't put inline styling in your HTML, especially not when that HTML is in your JS. Use a separate stylesheet to apply styling to the content. In addition, there is no `<bold />` element in HTML. Use CSS to apply `font-weight` to the `i` element instead.

Here's a working example:

```js
let network = ['ABC', 'DES', 'FDD', 'BGR'];
let html = network.map(item => `<span>${item}</span>`);

document.querySelector('#foo').innerHTML = html.join(`<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>`);
```

```css
#foo span {
  border: 3px dotted #399bff;
}

#foo i {
  color: #d77300;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display the output normally without the arrow. Check if it not the last index, add the arrow; otherwise; skip the arrow.

```
for (i=0;i<network.length;i++){
    temp = "<span style = 'border:3px dotted #399bff;'>" + network[i] + "</span>";
    if (i !== network.length-1){
        temp += "<bold style = 'color : #d77300;'> <i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i></bold>"
    }
    network[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: its displaying now like this **ABCDESFDDBGR--->**... i want lke this **ABC--->DES--->FDD--->BGR**

Comment: @Batool It shouldn't display like that. Are you sure you are running this code exactly as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Process the first element. and add subsequent elements with the arrows first.

```js
network=['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'];
network[0] = "<span style = 'border:3px dotted #399bff;'>" + network[0];
for (i=1;i<network.length;i++){
    temp ="</span><bold style = 'color : #d77300;'> <i> --></i></bold>"+"<span style = 'border:3px dotted #399bff;'>" + network[i]; 
    network[i] = temp;   
    }
document.write(network);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
network = ['ABC', 'DES', 'FDD', 'BGR'];
String(network).replaceAll(',',' --> ');              

//'ABC --> DES --> FDD --> BGR'
```

*simple*, but **not a good answer** for learners

Comment: This completely ignores the HTML in the required output.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let network = ['ABC', 'DES', 'FDD', 'BGR']; 
for (i = 0; i < network.length; i++) {
 temp = "<span style = 'border:3px dotted #399bff;'>" + network[i] + "</span>"
  if (i != network.length-1) {
  temp +=" <bold style = 'color : #d77300;'> <i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i></bold>";
  }
 network[i] = temp; 
} 
console.log(network.join());
```

an if condition to print arrows execpt last 1  
[ ***network.length - 1*** ]